# Adicionar uma linha em um DataGridView com uma QUERY como DataSource

Tags: c#, entity-framework, query, datagridview, datasource

Primeiramente eu criei um DGV e configurei ele da maneira que eu preciso, coloquei os nomes das colunas e formatei coluna por coluna da forma que eu preciso, adicionando o valor padrão para nulo, formatação do texto, tipo da entrada, etc.. E após isso...

Eu estou utilizando o Entity Framework, sendo assim, criei uma query que me retorna uma tabela, com três colunas e inseri no DGV da seguinte forma:

```
 var query = context.DOWNTIME.Where(Corrida => Corrida.CORRIDA == Int32.Parse(corrida) && Corrida.DATAFIM != null)
                                                .Select(Corrida => new { Corrida.DATAINICIO, Corrida.DATAFIM, Corrida.MINUTOS });
    
p.dataGridView2.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

Depois de inserir as três primeiras colunas, que são do tipo DateTime e uma Double, eu tbm adicionei duas colunas do tipo ComboBox e inseri outra query em cada ComboBoxCell da seguinte forma:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in p.dataGridView2.Rows)
{
   DataGridViewComboBoxCell theCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)p.dataGridView2[row.Cells[0].ColumnIndex, row.Cells[0].RowIndex];
   var result = context.GrupoDescricao.Select(GrupoDescricao => GrupoDescricao.Grupo).Distinct().ToList();
   theCell.Items.Clear();
   theCell.Items.AddRange(result.ToArray());

   DataGridViewComboBoxCell theCell1 = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)p.dataGridView2[row.Cells[1].ColumnIndex, row.Cells[1].RowIndex];
   var result1 = context.GrupoDescricao.Select(GrupoDescricao => GrupoDescricao.Descricao).ToList();
   theCell1.Items.Clear();
   theCell1.Items.AddRange(result1.ToArray());
 }
```

E por fim tem uma coluna de texto para Observações, totalizando 6 colunas.

Tudo esta funcionando como deveria, porém agora que preciso implementar uma nova funcionalidade, estou precisando alterar valores neste DGV, adicionar linhas, remover linhas e não estou conseguindo. Quando eu altero um valor ele volta o valor antigo, eu consigo alterar a cor da célula mas o valor dentro não, acredito que esteja associado diretamente com a fonte de dados, logo só alterando na fonte, mas eu não sei como que eu posso adicionar uma linha ou remover dentro de uma query e na posição que eu preciso, pois o usuário vai selecionar a linha e eu devo remover ou adicionar uma linha abaixo.

Eu já pesquisei bastante e na maioria das soluções as pessoas utilizam DataTable, BindingSource, e eu não queria alterar o meu DGV que ja esta todo padronizado da forma que eu preciso, inclusive com a coluna de ComboBoxCell e as querys inseridas em cada célula.

Eu ja tentei:

**DGV.add**

**DGV.Insert**

**DGV.Row[index].Cell[index].Value**

todos estes métodos comuns de adicionar linhas, remover ou alterar valor.

Agradeço desde já a ajuda de todos! Sei que ficou extenso e mesmo assim vai faltar bastante coisa, então estou a disposição para trazer as informações que precisam.

Abraço.